# Selecting a number of lines in visual mode in vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have a vim plugin that works mainly with the visual mode. One of its commands sends the visually selected region to an interpreter.

However, I would like to select the first 3105 lines of a file.

`1,3105mycommand` does not work, this is not implemented in the plugin.

Is there a vim command `xx` that, after invoking `1,3105xx` would visually select the first 3105 lines?

Answer (score 2):

An alternate method:

If the plugin only looks at visual mode's marks, then this might suffice:

```
1k<
3015k>
```

If it actually needs the visual mode to be on, then you would need to also add

```
normal gv
```

`:help :k`, `:help gv`

Note that nvim will start in character-wise visual mode, so change the last line to `normal gvV` for nvim.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple: in visual mode one can use the `3105G` command in command mode, typed blindly and that extends the visually selected region.

Comment: To put it in a command, `normal 1GV3105G` will select lines 1-3105. Dunno why mine has 2 votes and this none, I did say that was an alternate method :) This is way easier to do.